# Prevent more than one animation in jquery solution breaks after spamming links

Tags: jquery

I have 4 links on my page which fade their respective divs in and out as well as adjusting the containing div's height where necessary.

When the user spams these links the divs get out of sync or overlap each other. I have researched this and the two possible options are to use the .stop() method or a boolean variable which is checked onclick of each link.

I have tried implementing both without any joy. They do stop more than one function happening at once but after attempting to spam the links they will eventually break not fading anything in or out.

Could somebody explain what I have done wrong? Thanks

```
var animation_enabled;
animation_enabled = 0;


function open_labels_div(){
    if(animation_enabled == 1){
        return;
    }
    else{
        animation_enabled = 1;
        if($("#labels_div").is(':hidden')){
            if($("#charts_div").is(':visible')){
                $("#charts_div").fadeOut(400, function() {
                    $("#labels_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                        $("#charts_div").css("display","none");
                        $("#labels_div").css("display","inline-block");
                        animation_enabled = 0;
                    });
                });
            }
            else if($("#blank_charts_div").is(':visible')){
                $("#blank_charts_div").fadeOut(400, function() {
                    $("#labels_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                        $("#blank_charts_div").css("display","none");
                        $("#labels_div").css("display","inline-block");
                        animation_enabled = 0;
                    });
                });
            }
            else if($("#reorder_div").is(':visible')){
                var minus = $("#reorder_div").height()-100;
                $('#tab_content').animate({'height': '-='+minus},800,"linear", function() {
                    $("#reorder_div").fadeOut(400);
                    $("#labels_div").fadeIn(800, function (){
                        $("#reorder_div").css("display","none");
                        $("#labels_div").css("display","inline-block");
                        animation_enabled = 0;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

function open_charts_div(){
    if(animation_enabled == 1){
        return;
    }
    else{
        animation_enabled = 1;
        if($("#charts_div").is(':hidden')){
            if($("#labels_div").is(':visible')){
                $("#labels_div").fadeOut(400, function() {
                    $("#charts_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                        $("#labels_div").css("display","none");
                        $("#charts_div").css("display","inline-block");
                        animation_enabled = 0;
                    });
                });
            }
            else if($("#blank_charts_div").is(':visible')){
                $("#blank_charts_div").fadeOut(400, function() {
                    $("#charts_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                        $("#blank_charts_div").css("display","none");
                        $("#charts_div").css("display","inline-block");
                        animation_enabled = 0;
                    });
                });
            }
            else if($("#reorder_div").is(':visible')){
                var minus = $("#reorder_div").height()-100;
                $('#tab_content').animate({'height': '-='+minus},800,"linear", function() {
                    $("#reorder_div").fadeOut(400);
                    $("#charts_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                        $("#reorder_div").css("display","none");
                        $("#charts_div").css("display","inline-block");
                        animation_enabled = 0;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

function open_blank_charts_div(){
    if(animation_enabled == 1){
        return;
    }
    else{
        animation_enabled = 1;
        if($("#blank_charts_div").is(':hidden')){
            if($("#labels_div").is(':visible')){
                $("#labels_div").fadeOut(400, function() {
                    $("#blank_charts_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                        $("#labels_div").css("display","none");
                        $("#blank_charts_div").css("display","inline-block");
                        animation_enabled = 0;
                    });
                });
            }
            else if($("#charts_div").is(':visible')){
                $("#charts_div").fadeOut(400, function() {
                    $("#blank_charts_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                        $("#charts_div").css("display","none");
                        $("#blank_charts_div").css("display","inline-block");
                        animation_enabled = 0;
                    });
                });
            }
            else if($("#reorder_div").is(':visible')){
                var minus = $("#reorder_div").height()-100;
                $('#tab_content').animate({'height': '-='+minus},800,"linear", function() {
                    $("#reorder_div").fadeOut(400);
                    $("#blank_charts_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                        $("#reorder_div").css("display","none");
                        $("#blank_charts_div").css("display","inline-block");
                        animation_enabled = 0;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

function open_reorder(){
    if(animation_enabled == 1){
        return;
    }
    else{
        animation_enabled = 1;
        if($("#reorder_div").is(':hidden')){
            var add = $("#reorder_div").height()-100;
            $('#tab_content').animate({'height': '+='+add},800,"linear", function() {
                if($("#labels_div").is(':visible')){
                    $("#labels_div").fadeOut(400);
                    $("#reorder_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                        $("#labels_div").css("display","none");
                        $("#reorder_div").css("display","inline-block");
                        animation_enabled = 0;
                    });
                }
                else if($("#charts_div").is(':visible')){
                    $("#charts_div").fadeOut(400);
                    $("#reorder_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                        $("#charts_div").css("display","none");
                        $("#reorder_div").css("display","inline-block");
                        animation_enabled = 0;
                    });
                }
                else if($("#blank_charts_div").is(':visible')){
                    $("#blank_charts_div").fadeOut(400);
                    $("#reorder_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
                        $("#blank_charts_div").css("display","none");
                        $("#reorder_div").css("display","inline-block");
                        animation_enabled = 0;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

<div id='options_tabs'>
    <ul>
        <li onclick='open_labels_div()'><a>Labels</a></li>
        <li onclick='open_charts_div()'><a>Charts</a></li>
        <li onclick='open_blank_charts_div()'><a>Blank Charts</a></li>
        <li onclick='open_reorder()'><a>Reorder</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='tab_content'>
    <div id='labels_div'>
        <p>labels content</p>
    </div>
    <div id='charts_div'>
        <p>charts content</p>
    </div>
    <div id='blank_charts_div'>
        <p>blank charts content</p>
    </div>
    <div id='reorder_div'>
        <p>reorder content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your html structure also? I think your js is very long and can be really improved

Comment: ok added to the bottom :)

Comment: Just to be sure: you want only 1 div opened at a time?

Comment: yes one div at a time, if you want to make it more efficient go for it but explain the changes so I can learn from this instead of just fixing it :) cheers!

Comment: Yes that's the way. How are your divs at start? all visible? all hidden?

Comment: labels_div is visible onload and the rest are hidden

Comment: OK. Basic question: are you using jquery-ui in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, I was working...

### 1st solution, based on your initial developments

Here I used the idea you got from the beginning: when you click on a `li` item, a javascript function is called. To reduce the code length, I made the following:

- Used only 1 function, the same for all buttons, which use variables (see comments in the script part)
- Used a link between the id I gave to the `li` items and the `div` items corresponding: the li item called `itemA` has a div called `itemA_div` (important for the script showing/hiding divs)
- Bind the function with jquery `click()` instead of your javascript `onclick`

Html markup:

```
<div id='options_tabs'>
    <ul>
        <li id="labels"><a>Labels</a></li>
        <li id="charts"><a>Charts</a></li>
        <li id="blank_charts"><a>Blank Charts</a></li>
        <li id="reorder"><a>Reorder</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='tab_content'>
    <div id='labels_div'>
        <p>labels content</p>
    </div>
    <div id='charts_div'>
        <p>charts content</p>
    </div>
    <div id='blank_charts_div'>
        <p>blank charts content</p>
    </div>
    <div id='reorder_div'>
        <p>reorder content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script (with comments to help):

```
var animation_enabled;
animation_enabled = 0;

// On click event, call "changeDivs" function
$("#options_tabs ul li").click(changeDivs);

// changeDivs function
function changeDivs() {
    // If the flag is true, animation is running, so trying to launch another one
    if(animation_enabled == 1){
        return;
    } else {
        // If not currently animating, do the div visibility change
        animation_enabled = 1;

        // 1st - get the id of the li item clicked (calling the function, so I used this)
        var originItem = $(this).attr('id');
        // Then set a variable which is the content div that will be visible
        var destinationDiv = $("#" + originItem + "_div");

        // Here I will fadeOut all div inside tab_content which are not #myLiItemName_div, and wait the end of the fade with promise(), then fadeIn the div #myLiItemName_div
        $("#tab_content div:not(#" + originItem + "_div)").fadeOut(750).promise().done(function() {
            destinationDiv.fadeIn(800).promise().done(function() { 
                animation_enabled = 0; });;
        });        
    }
}
```

This jsfiddle show this working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/nrobert/8nCAJ/5/

---

### 2nd solution, using jquery UI

Using jquery UI "accordion" widget, it's very light:

Html part:

```
<div id='options_tabs'>
    <h3>Labels</h3>
    <div>Labels content</div>
    <h3>Charts</h3>
    <div>Charts content</div>
    <h3>Blank Charts</h3>
    <div>Blank Charts content</div>
    <h3>Reorder</h3>
    <div>Reorder content</div>
</div>
```

Script part:

```
$( "#options_tabs" ).accordion();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nrobert/8nCAJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Before starting an animation on one of these elements, add a call to jQuery.clearQueue().  This should clear the spammed animations before starting the next.

http://api.jquery.com/clearqueue/

`$("#charts_div").clearQueue().fadeOut(400, function() {
    $("#labels_div").fadeIn(400, function (){
        $("#charts_div").css("display","none");
        $("#labels_div").css("display","inline-block");
        animation_enabled = 0;
    });
});`

Comment: same problem, this technically does what I want it to (prevents multiple calls to these functions) however after spamming the links as a user they break and won't do any fading in or out of divs